# How to tell when Iframe has called all links in externall called page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

When an Iframe is loading, hlow will I know when it is complete and all external files have been called by the html/javascript page that the iframe is calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an iframe is loaded, it triggers the event load, so you could add some javascript:

```
document.frames["iframe_name"].onload = function() { alert('Loaded'); };
```